# Traversing HTML DOM Elements in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have this segment of code here

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Title One</th>
        <th>Title Two</th>
        <th>Title Three</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($foos as $foo): ?>
            <tr>
                <td id="x"><?php echo $foo->bar1; ?></td>
                <td id="y"><?php echo $foo->bar2; ?></td>
                <td id="z"><?php echo $foo->bar3; ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#x').on('click', function(){
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
</script>
```

Suppose I have 10 rows of data there, how will I be able to reference the exact element I have clicked? For example row number 5, how will jQuery know that I have clicked row 5? I can't go writing `<td id="x1">`,`<td id="x2">`,`<td id="x3">`,`<td id="x4">` because I can be having a thousand records.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `$(this)` will hold reference to the clicked element. I may misunderstood your question. Could you please be more specific?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `closest('tr')` to find the nearest parent `tr` element, then `index()` to get the row number. Try this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var rowIndex = $tr.index();
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/a8obp7kh/)

Also note that you should remove the `id` attribute from the `td` elements in your PHP loop, otherwise you will duplicate them, which is invalid and may lead to JS or rendering issues.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function() {
    var rowNumber = $(this).closest('tr').index() + 1;
    var content = $(this).html();
    console.log(rowNumber);
    console.log(content);
});
```

You do not need to know via some sort of identification which you have clicked as jQuery is aware of the element you clicked in relation to the overall DOM.

You do need to add 1 to the row number variable as the index starts counting at 0.

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sc7xt0ve/)

Comment: I think we can assume the OP will know how to deal with 0 indexed rows. I don't think they literally meant "if I click the fifth row I want a 5". It is *more* likely they just want access to the row, so index() will be redundant on all the answers :)

Comment: Perhaps @TrueBlueAussie, but it cannot hurt to state it.

Comment: Agreed it is worth pointing out (have updated own answer to do that too), but no point compensating for it :)

Comment: Very nice :) and thank you for using `this.id` initially haha

Comment: I do what I can @SterlingArcher - save for reading too quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.index()` if you need to know the position of the element.

```
$('td').on('click',function()
{
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').index())
})
```

Otherwise `$(this)` will be the element itself.

Comment: This one does not target the row index. There are no `LI` in the example

Comment: Yeah - sorry - that was my bad. I just made a quick fiddle to get the index. I can fix it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you listen for clicks on the TDs, you can get the `closest` ancestor TR and simply see what it's index position is within its parent with `index()`:

```
$('table td').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

If the rows/TDs are added dynamically, use a delegated version of on instead:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td' function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

This one applies the selector only when the event occurs.

Notes:

- `index` returns values starting at 0.
- You probably do not actually care about the index value itself, but just the `closest('tr')` in order to do other operations.

Update:

if you want a row id in the table, apply that to the TR element so you get

```
<tr data-parent_id="myidhere">
```

and access with

```
$('table td').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('parent_id');
});
```

Comment: Under your notes, note number 2, I want to get the id (from the database) for that particular row. Where do I place my `data-parent_id` attribute?

Comment: @Richie: Updated. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: ... oh it's so lonely at the bottom here... with an early answer... but no fan club :>

Answer (score 0):

If you need the row number, you could use the index function. The easiest way to do this is to change the click handler (assuming you want to get the index of any td in your tr that is clicked). You don't even need to put ids on your TDs anymore:

```
<tr class = 'clickiness'>
    <td id="x"><?php echo $foo->bar1; ?></td>
    <td id="y"><?php echo $foo->bar2; ?></td>
    <td id="z"><?php echo $foo->bar3; ?></td>
</tr>
<script>
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '.clickiness' ).click( function( event ) {
        var $tds = $( this ).children();
        var $clickedTD = $( event.target );
        var clickedIndex = $clickedTD.index( $tds );    // the zero-based index
    });
});
</script>
```

What I'm doing here is setting setting the click handler to the TR, so when anything inside that TR is clicked, the function will run, and then I'm using the event variable to get the actual element that was clicked.